# add items in list from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have that model class

```
public class CV
{
    ...
    public List<Education> education { get; set; }
    public Education newEducation { get; set; }

    public void addEducation(CV cv)
    {
        cv.education = cv.education ?? new List<Education>();
        cv.education.Add(cv.newEducation);
    }
    ...
}
```

and in view I have:

```
@model solution.Models.CV
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newEducation.Faculty)
...
```

and desired textboxes for that education class. Now I want to add these items in my list after I click to add button:

```
<div class="add-education">
 <a href="" class="add-education-button">add education</a>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

In my `CV` class there are another lists too. So I want to do that by that way (from one model)

Comment: may be you don't describe your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to post to Controller's action from html input:

```
<form method="post" action="yourNameController/nameAction">
 <div>
   @model solution.Models.CV
   ...
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newEducation.Faculty)
 </div>
 <div class="add-education">
 <button type="submit" class="add-education-button">add education</button>
</div>
</form>
```